# Change printer group permission with script?

Tags: permissions, powershell, script, printer, acl

How do i change the user group "everyone" permissions on a local printer using a script?
I've been digging around and something's telling me to use ACL using powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the below resources and quoted steps for detail on setting printer permissions via command line in Windows (both PowerShell and Batch).

> ### [Batch modify printer permissions](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22124166/Batch-modify-printer-permissions.html)
>
> If you want to do it with a comand line tool, get subinacl from the
>   Resource Kit:
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e8ba3e56-d8fe-4a91-93cf-ed6985e3927b&displaylang=en
>
> ```
> subinacl /printer <\printer name> /grant=Everyone=F
> ```
>
> or by modifying Steve's script:
>
> ```
> for /f %a in ('net share ^| find "Spooled"') do subinacl /printer %a /grant=Everyone=F
> ```
>
> <sub>[source](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22124166/Batch-modify-printer-permissions.html)</sub>

---

> ### [PowerShell - Add Printer Permission](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Add-Printer-Permission-c0ece1f3)
>
> Windows Server 2012 comes with the PrintManagement module, which makes
>   automation Management of Printers easier. But testing cmdlets like
>   Add-Printer and Set-Printer I noticed that you can set Printer
>   Permission only using the Parameter -PermissionSDDL . These Parameters
>   in both cmdlets expect Printer Permission using Security Definition
>   Description Language (SDDL) which is not what you can type on the
>   command line that easy.
>
> ```
> Function Add-LHSPrinterPermissionSDDL 
> { 
>
> [cmdletbinding(   
>     ConfirmImpact = 'Low', 
>     SupportsShouldProcess = $false 
> )]   
>
> [OutputType('System.String')] 
>
> param( 
>     [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$False, 
>         HelpMessage='A Security Group or User like "Domain\GroupName" or "Domain\UserName"')] 
>     [String]$Account, 
>
>     [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$False)] 
>     [String]$existingSDDL 
> ) 
>
> BEGIN { 
>
>     Set-StrictMode -Version Latest 
>
>     ${CmdletName} = $Pscmdlet.MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name 
>
>
> } # end BEGIN 
>
> PROCESS { 
>
>     try  
>     { 
>         $isContainer = $false 
>         $isDS = $false 
>         $SecurityDescriptor = New-Object -TypeName ` 
>             Security.AccessControl.CommonSecurityDescriptor ` 
>             $isContainer, $isDS, $existingSDDL 
>
>         Write-Verbose "Adding Permission for Group $Account" 
>         #get the SID for the specified Group and add it to the SDDL 
>         $NTAccount = New-Object Security.Principal.NTAccount $Account 
>         $NTAccountSid = $NTAccount.Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value 
>
>         $SecurityDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl.AddAccess( 
>             [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow, 
>             $NTAccountSid, 
>             268435456, #full control all operations 
>             [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None, 
>             [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None) | Out-Null 
>
>
>         return $SecurityDescriptor.GetSddlForm("All") 
>     } 
>     catch [Exception]  
>     { 
>         Write-Error -Message "Failed To Generate SDDL (review inner exception):`n $_.Message" ` 
>             -Exception $_.Exception 
>     } 
> } # end PROCESS 
>
> END { Write-Verbose "Function ${CmdletName} finished." } 
> } #end Function Add-LHSPrinterPermissionSDDL
> ```
>
> <sub>[source](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Add-Printer-Permission-c0ece1f3)</sub>

---

### Additional Resources

- [Scripting Printer Permissions](https://www.uvm.edu/~gcd/2013/06/scripting-printer-permissions/)